# find the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on my webpage i have multiple list items which all have onclick listener.
i need javascript / jquery code to find the id of the element that was clicked and hence invoked the listener.

Comment: Read the jQuery manual, you should be able to find it somewhere.

Comment: Can we dismiss these type of questions a "Have you tried a Google search?" or is that wrong?

Comment: i wouldnt be posting here if i had found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the id of the clicked on .

```
$('li').click(function(){
alert( this.id );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use this keyword

```
  this.id;
```

Comment: Where? What are you returning it to?

Comment: @D_N - thats up to OP how he uses it. I have provided enough to what OP requires. can use a general function and implement the functionality he wants.

Comment: @D_N - and FYI that in no sense is a proper reason to downvote the post.